# I like to work individually, but I work in groups

Tags: riddle

> I like to work individually, 
>  but I work in groups.
>
> I like to work in my office, 
>  but I work in the field.
>
> Yet I am satisfied.

What am I?

Comment: I came here for a workplace question, I always confuse the logos...

Comment: @Noir You're not the only one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are a

> mathematician, specifically an algebraist.

I like to work individually, but I work in groups.

> Groups are a fundamental algebraic construct.

I like to work in my office, but I work in the field.

> Fields are another fundamental algebraic construct.

Comment: This is the intended answer.

Comment: Well, at least I was pretty close :D

Answer (score 14):

I can think of a few possibilities but I'll go with this one... is it

> a Bee

I like to work individually, but I work in groups.

> Working individually, but also working as part of a larger group

I like to work in my office, but I work in the field.

> Working in the beehive, but working in the field (the field being a field of flowers for example)

Also, and I really don't think this was intended - it's more for my own amusement

> If you read the first letters of the first two paragraphs aloud, I b I b (ie. "I bee, I bee")

Answer (score 12):

You are a

> particle physicist

I like to work individually, 
but I work in groups.

> Group theory is a fundamental part of particle physics

I like to work in my office, 
but I work in the field.

> Quantum Field Theory is the basic description of quantum particles

Comment: Very nice answer, not exactly what I meant, but certainly a possibility.

Answer (score 4):

> A programmer?

I like to work individually, 
but I work in groups.

> A lone worker, but the project is called 'Groups'

I like to work in my office, 
but I work in the field.

> The 'field' of computer programming

Comment: I don't find this answer very strong. Almost anything can have a project called groups.

Comment: @wythagoras But it fits the other clues...

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> vowel

I like to work individually,

> Most of the vowels here are singles and are perfectly functional.

but I work in groups.

> Vowels can work in groups too. Groups has a pair of vowels.

I like to work in my office,

> Again, all the vowels are separated by consonants.

but I work in the field.

> But they work together in Field.

Answer (score 1):

It think you are

> Me in high school

I like to work individually, 
but I work in groups.

> I worked better individually, but I was frequently assigned to work on group projects instead

I like to work in my office, 
but I work in the field.

> I preferred doing work at home, but often had to do work while at school. I'm not sure you know so much about me in high school but it's a little creepy.

Comment: This is of course not a serious answer